# AEM DAM Metadata User Access

Tags: metadata, aem, dam

I have created a user group that specifically has access to three asset folders in the AEM DAM. These users have read/modify/create/delete permissions, yet they cannot add metadata tags to an assets detail page.

Any suggestions? Is there a step I am missing?

The metadata fields do not even render on the asset detail page for this user group. As an admin, I can see the metadata list field populating. I believe I am missing a permissions box. I have read documentation that says that read/modify access to the folder should be enough, but this is not working.

Application AEM 6.3: DAM

Comment: Do those users only have access to the folders and _nothing_ else? Because the asset properties etc. is a separate tool that the users need access to. I am thinking about `/libs/dam/gui/content/assets` or `/libs/cq/core/content/nav/assets/*` or `/libs/wcm/core/content/damadmin`. If your users do not have permissions on those folders or required sub-folders they might not be able to see properties etc.

Answer (score 0):

The user group must have read access to /conf/global/settings/dam/adminui-extension/metadataschema since the metadata fields are rendered from the above path.